# Expo fails to run due to "sharp module compiled against a different version of Node.js"

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

My laptop recently died, and I'm trying to run Expo on my new machine  (Windows 10). I installed the latest versions of Node and NPM and ran `npm install -g expo-cli`. When I run 'expo start' I get the following error:

```
The module '\\?\C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

I tried reinstalling Node and Expo. I tried deleting node_modules and `package.lock`, which didn't help. I ran `npm rebuild` and that didn't work. I ran `npm update` on the specified module and that didn't fix it either.

EDIT: previously focused on an old project not running, but Expo won't run period even on a newly initialized project

Comment: Does the Expo not install normally?

Comment: It says it installed fine, but it won’t actually run. I installed it with NPM.